# What is the easiest way to get the default R sf map plot default legend back?

Tags: r, plot, r-sf

I have been trying to display a legend on a choropleth plot but finding the R docuemntation for legend a bit difficult to get my head around. Been reading it for a few hours now.

I see that the following gets a legend:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
world <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale='medium',returnclass = 'sf')
class(world)
plot(world[,"adm0_dif"])
```

But the following, does not:

```
plot(world[,"adm0_dif"], col=sf.colors(n = nrow(world), alpha=0.5))
```

In the R help age for `plot` for sf object it states:

> "Specifying col suppresses plotting the legend key."

So, I wonder what is the simplest way to get the default legend back if that is all I want.

Answer (score 1):

I use ggplot more than I do base R plot so I am not sure how to add the legend back with base R. Additionally, I am not familiar with the rnaturalearth package and data so all I've done is replicate your plot with ggplot and add a legend. I am not sure if this is the legend you want but all I've done is make the exact same plot with ggplot and added a legend. You can then customise the legend if it's not what you are looking for.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = 1:nrow(world))) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "", alpha = 0.5, option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt") +
  theme_classic()
```

For side by side plots of multiple variables we can use the `gridExtra` package.

```r
library(gridExtra)

plot1 <-  ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = 1:nrow(world))) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "", alpha = 1, option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt") +
  ggtitle("adm0_dif")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"))

plot2 <-  ggplot(data = world) +
    geom_sf(aes(fill = labelrank)) +
    scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "", alpha = 1, option = "plasma", trans = "sqrt") +
    ggtitle("labelrank") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
          panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"))

grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2)
```

For plotting variables that are not coded by number, like `featurecla`, use `scale_fill_manual` instead like so

```r
plot_fea <-  ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = featurecla), show.legend = F) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = c("mediumaquamarine"))+
  ggtitle("featurecla") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white"))

plot_fea
```

Note I've only supplied value ("mediumaquamarine") to values in `scale_fill_manual` because it only contains one unique variable. The number of colours passed to value has to match the number of unique variables in the column.

Comment: What I am actually after is a multi grid/facet plot. Like multiple variables plotting at the same time on the one sf dataframe. This is easy with base `plot`. Maybe you know how to make the same in `ggplot`? The following command makes a multiplot: `plot(world)`

Comment: You can get the same plot in ggplot but that would require using the gridExtra package to get side by side plots. I can't place that code in a comment as it's a bit long, so I suggest you ask another question as what you want differs from what you've asked here.

Comment: What's the matter with the plot you get with plot(world)? Are you trying to plot specific variables other than the 9 that get plotted? If so, why not just subset the dataframe and plot that? Are you looking for something extra?

Comment: `plot(world)` has no legend.

Comment: Again, I'm not familiar with the data but some of the columns in world would be difficult to have a legend especially with 9 side by side plots. The admin column for example has 241 discrete names of countries, which would require a legend with the country names. I can get you a side by side plot with variables that are grouped and then give a legend for each individual plot. I can edit my answer with an example, then you can add which ever specific ones you want.